# Zend Framework passing a variable to all views from a controller to anything outside of $this->layout->content()

Tags: php, zend-framework, variables

Ok, the subject makes no sense so Ill try to better describe it here.

Zend Frame work in use here. And I have run into a problem passing variables to my views, well the views included into the "top.phtml" that make up the template. What I am trying to do is implement a breadcrumb concept. The bread crumb file is included into the top.phtml before the content view file. So the breadcrumb variable isn't defined as far as the breadcrumb file is concerned.

I can print_r my array of settings for the breadcrumbs within the controllers view, no problem so it is working I know that much, just anything above that view in particular in the order of things can't get the variable. So I guess what I am looking to have answered is is there a means off passing a variable to the overall scheme of things similar in concept to

```
$this->view->variable_name = blah;
```

where something as high as the top.phtml can pick it up for use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+1 for everyone for giving me a clue, however none of the above worked well in my favor. However between them all, they lead me towards finding my answer which is

`Zend_Registry`

In my Controller I built my array and passed it to Zend_Registry like

```
    $breadArray = array(
        array("icon"=>"i_robot", "href"=>"systems/"),
        array("href"=>"metrics","text"=>"Metrics")
    );
    Zend_Registry::set('breaded_crumbs', $breadArray);
```

Then in my breadcrumb.phtml which is loaded before the content and view I used

```
print_r(Zend_Registry::get('breaded_crumbs'));
```

to see if it was working, and it gave me the array's so I for anyone in the future looking to extend a variable outside of the view itself, the registry seems to be the way to go. I tried placeholder and layout, both gave me errors about not being something or another, and when I got them to work in part I wasn't getting what I was expecting.

Comment: Just be aware that by doing this you are setting global state, which is generally considered bad practice. However, if you are aware of the pitfalls and have documented your decision a limited use like this may be OK.

Comment: Yea, this isn't something I'd user far and wide, as its in part against the grain of why one would use MVC in general, this is one of those rare instances where passing a small bit of data globally in such a fashion is acceptable for me.

Answer (score 3):

You may be looking for [Placeholders](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.placeholder).

Example:

Setting a placeholder value from a controller:

```
$this->view->placeholder('some_placeholder_name')->set('blah');
```

Setting a placeholder value from a view

```
$this->placeholder('some_placeholder_name')->set('blah');
```

Retrieving the placeholder value in a view script *or* layout:

```
$value = $this->placeholder('some_placeholder_name');
```

Placeholder content is rendered towards the end of your application execution so the value set in your controller should be available in your top level `top.phtml` view script.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work:

```
$this->layout()->breadcrumbs = ...
```

And then print `$this->layout()->breadcrumbs` in your top.phtml.

- [Zend Layout](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.layout.quickstart.html)

Answer (score 1):

After sending ***hours*** trying to get `placeholder()` to work with `partialLoop()`, I finally gave up and hacked a fix to pass vars to a partial:

```
$vars = (array) $this->getVars();
foreach ($this->rows as $row) {
    $partialVars = array(
        'row' => $row,
        'vars' => $vars,
    );
    echo $this->partial('row.phtml', $partialVars);
}
```

ugly, but it worked.